# Problem with the right-click mouse button on the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My ergonomic keyboard does not have a specific button for right clicking. Looks like the Windows key has been combined with the right-click button. But I don't know how click it so it works like right-click mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to either toggle or hold an "Fn" key somewhere on the keyboard. Look in the lower left corner (near left-ctrl) or in the upper right, to the right of your F12 key. Then, try holding the Fn key and pressing the Windows key.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to access context menus in Windows, even if your keyboard doesn't have a dedicated key or if the key doesn't work as expected.  As noted by @jcrawfordor you could look for an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, but that's unlikely on a desktop keyboard.  Another option is to try <kbd>ALT-GR</kbd> + <kbd>WIN</kbd> to access the context menu function on your windows key.